# Execute SQL Statament - Power Automate

Tags: sql, power-automate

I'm trying to update a Table on my database using a connector `Execute SQL Statement`, however, I'm getting the same error `error on SQL Statement syntax near ..`

The table that I want to insert values is very simple:

[image]

I'm trying to just insert values on the 3 first columns `VIN`, `PN5D` & `RO` and I'm using the following statement

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_RPA3] (VIN, PN5D, RO)
VALUES (%VIN_F%, %PN5D_F%, %RO_F%)
```

All 3 variables `%VIN_F%`, `%PN5D_F%` & `%RO%` are texts as the prints below proves (Valor de texto = Text value), therefore, should be no problem to insert it on the table

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me?

More detail from the error:

> Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.SDK.ActionException: Erro na instrução >SQLIncorrect syntax near 'BHBH41DBHP767923'. ---> >System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Incorrect syntax near 'BHBH41DBHP767923'.
> em System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.ProcessResults(OleDbHResult hr)
> em System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.NextResult()
> em System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior >behavior, String method)
> em System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> em System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
> DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
> srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
> em System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
> startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
> CommandBehavior behavior)
> em System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
> em
> Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.Database.Actions.DatabaseActions.ExecuteS
> QLStatement(Variant connectionString, Variant sqlConnectionVariable,
> Variant sqlCommand, Variant& result, Int32 timeout, Int32 getConnection)
> --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
> em
> Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.Database.Actions.ExecuteSqlStatement.Execute(ActionContext context)
> em
> Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Robin.Engine.Execution.ActionRunner.Run(IActionStatement statement, Dictionary`2 inputArguments, Dictionary`2 outputArguments)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it looks like you missing the single quotes that denote these values are VARCHAR

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_RPA3] (VIN, PN5D, RO)
VALUES ('%VIN_F%', '%PN5D_F%', '%RO_F%')
```

Comment: It was worked, thanks